# Why can a Rust struct be defined without a semicolon?

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust and the chapter for structs gives an example of a struct without a `;` at the end. It compiles but I have no idea why this is allowed.

```
fn main() {
    struct User {
        username: String,
        email: String,
        sign_in_count: u64,
        active: bool,
    }
}
```

... same question goes for functions, actually.

Comment: Rust doesn't allow `struct {...} variableName;` the way that C does, so there's no reason to require a semicolon there. And I don't think there's any language that requires a semicolon after function definitions.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? In the end, it boils down to "because the grammar and the Rust parser allow it", which in turn boils down to "because that's the way it was defined" which in turn boils down to "because someone wanted it that way".

Comment: With grammar/syntax question, it's better to ask "why we should/must add it", and currently there is no reason to add it.

Comment: Surmising, but lexically a semicolon provides an end to a statement, e.g. `let a = 5;`. When there is a block `{}` we already have a lexical scope, an apparent end, hence a struct definition, function definition, or if expression doesn't need a semi-colon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Shepmaster said in the comment, the "reason" is that Rust defines so. Here I will explain the rules behind it.

Basically **you can omit `;` when it ends with `}`**. This will answer your question.

However, there are a number of exceptions to the rule:

### When `{}` appears indirectly

The rule above doesn't apply when `{}` appears indirectly, like

```
use std::io::{self, Read, Write}; // Here }; appears
```

or

```
let x = if cond {
    1
} else {
    2
}; // Here }; appears
```

In this case, `{}` isn't a direct part of `use`/`let`. So in this case you need `;`.

### Items

Items are things which you can also place outside of functions. That is, one of `extern crate`, `use`, `mod`, `struct`, `enum`, `union`, `type`, `trait`, `impl`, `fn`, `static`, `const`, `extern`, and macros.

You can place items either outside of functions or in a function. However, There is a difference between them:

- If it appears outside of functions, you **have to** omit `;` when unnecessary.
- If it appears in a function, you can also place `;` there. This is basically because the `;` itself is an **empty statement**.

Example:

```
struct A {} // You can't place ; here
fn main() {
    struct B {} // You can omit ; here
    struct C {}; // You can also place ; here
}
```

### The last expression

You have to omit `;` if

- It is the last statement in the block,
- it is an expression (items and `let` aren't expressions), and
- you want to return the value from the expression.

Example:

```
fn f() -> i32 {
    let x = 1;
    x + x // You want to return x + x, so you can't place `;` here
}
```

### Block expressions

`if`, `if let`, `match`, `loop`, `while`, `while let`, `for`, `unsafe`, and bare `{}` ends with `}`, so you can omit `;` after them. However, there is a slight effect if you place `;` here.

Example:

```
fn f(x: i32) -> i32 {
    if x < 10 {
        10
    } else {
        20
    }; // If you remove ; here, then you will see a compile error.
    42
}
```

In most cases, you don't have to place `;` here; instead you may have to place `;` in the blocks.

```
fn f(x: i32) -> i32 {
    if x < 10 {
        10;
    } else {
        20;
    }
    42
}
```

### Statement macros

In statement positions, you can write three different kinds of macros:

- `some_macro!()`/`some_macro![]`: this isn't in fact a statement macro; instead, this is a mere expression macro. It can't expand to items or `let`.
- `some_macro!{}`: this expands to zero or more statements.
- `some_macro!();`/`some_macro![];`/`some_macro!{};`: this also expands to zero or more statements; however, there is a very minor difference: `;` is added to the last expanded statement.

Comment: So block expressions don't need `;` iff their value is `()`?

Comment: Block expressions don't need `;` iff their value doesn't need to be explicitly changed to `()`. That means their value is already `()` or their value is actually used. Latter examples include those part of `let x =` and those which are the last sentence in another block.